# Regex not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

Whats wrong with this regular expression?

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d\s&#-\('"]{1,7}$/;
```

when I enter the following valid input, it fails:

```
a&'-#"2
```

Also check for 2 consecutive spaces within the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dash needs to be either escaped (`\-`) or placed at the end of the character class, or it will signify a range (as in `A-Z`), not a literal dash:

```
/^[A-Z\d\s&#('"-]{1,7}$/i
```

would be a better regex.

N. B: `[#-\(]` would have matched `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'` or `(`.

To address the added requirement of not allowing two consecutive spaces, use a lookahead assertion:

```
/^(?!.*\s{2})[A-Z\d\s&#('"-]{1,7}$/i
```

`(?!.*\s{2})` means "Assert that it's impossible to match (from the current position) any string followed by two whitespace characters". One caveat: The dot doesn't match newline characters.

Comment: Tim, thanks for pointing out the error. I was wondering how should I edit the given regex to handle two consecutive spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? Should they be allowed or not?

Comment: Sorry. I meant not allowed. 2 consecutive spaces not allowed

Comment: "but I guess your input can't contain any, can it?" Thats correct

Comment: OK; then the second regex should be just fine :)

Comment: Tim, its not validation this input: 3  -23

Comment: So weird, this new regex is not validating the old input either: a&'-#"

Comment: You must be having a typo somewhere. Did you copy the complete regex including the `/i` at the end?

Comment: Oops thats what I missed. the i

Comment: Sir, the regex link you gave doesnt contain /i at the end. Why so?

Comment: Because in Regexr, there's a case-insensitive button for that. Notice there are also nö slashes around the regex. Just a different way of expressing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `-` (hyphen) has a special meaning inside a character class, used for specifying ranges. Did you mean to escape it?:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d\s&#\-\('"]{1,7}$/;
```

This RegExp matches your input.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unescaped `-` in the middle of your character class. This means that you're actually searching for all characters between and including `#` and `(` (which are `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, and `(`). Either move it to the end or escape it with a backslash. Your regex should read:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d\s&#\('"-]{1,7}$/
```

or

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d\s&#\-\('"]{1,7}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the ; at the end and

```
^[a-zA-Z\d\s\&\#\-\(\'\"]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input does not match the regular expression. The problem here is the hyphen in you regexp. If you move it from its position after the '#' character to the start of the regex, like so:

```
/^[-a-zA-Z\d\s&#\('"]{1,7}$/;
```

everything is fine and dandy.

You can always use [Rubular](http://rubular.com/#) for checking your regular expressions. I use it on a regular (no pun intended) basis.